# Questions about Bash Script--How to count reviews within a file and filter out particular reviews?

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting. I am doing a course work about writing bash scripts to count reviews within a file and filter out particular reviews.
How do I use `grep` and `wc` at the same time in a bash script?

The file content looks like this:

```
URL: URL of the hotel

< Author1 >NAME OF THE AUTHOR1  
< Content >REVIEW1

< Author2 >NAME OF THE AUTHOR2  
< Content >REVIEW2
```

And the output of the script would be like:

```
% ./countreviews.sh path_to_reviews_folder
hotel_1322 50
hotel_21313 49
hotel_31331 45
```

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Offhand, bash doesn't strike me as a good choice of languages for this purpose. XQuery, f/e, has everything you need to search through HTML or XML to parse out individual components built in; doing that with bash involves using a bunch of 3rd-party tools. (Or are your "reviews" in a format that isn't HTML? Without details in the question, we're left at guessing).

Comment: Ideally, a good question should ask about *one* specific technical problem you encountered while trying to implement the program yourself, with enough details to let someone else produce that problem themselves. If you're trying to figure out where to get started and don't have a specific problem yet, then SO isn't typically the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For number one, you could simply use `curl -f` like you normally would inside your bash file. As far as the other questions, I you would use a variable (define using `VAR=0`, and step by using `VAR=VAR+1`). See [this tutorial](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html) for more info on how to do that. If you include more information about what reviews you mean, I could likely help you a little more.

Comment: See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -- questions that are too broad to permit a comprehensive answer should be clarified *first* (close functionality lets such questions be put on-hold until they're improved enough to be a useful knowledgebase addition).